# Is it possible to render an Angular component inside chartjs tooltips?

Tags: angular, chart.js

In an Angular app I'm working on, I would like to highly customize the **Chart.js tooltips**.

To this end, I want to render an **Angular Component** inside the ["External Custom Tooltip"](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips) (both for reusability and cleanliness of my code).

Is this doable?

The [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips) in Chart.js for Custom Tooltips only shows examples of rendering HTML inside the tooltip.

Comment: Maybe you can try to add a component with RendererFactory2 or Renderer2. https://angular.io/api/core/RendererFactory2